# Not Able to see the settings tab in sonar qube UI

Tags: sonarqube-4.5

I have installed sonarqube on my windows 64 bit machine,started the UI but not able to see the setting tab inside it, please suggest me what action should be taken.
Attaching a screen shot for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please attach the link so that we can help you.

To edit global settings (and indeed to see the tab) you will need admin privileges in sonar.

To edit project specific settings (and see its tab) you will need to navigate to the project, and you will need at least project admin privileges.